# Changing text at certain intervals in the day (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

So I am fairly new to JS and I am trying to implement a sort of schedule in my website. I have a schedule of speakers and they change every half hour. I would like to display the name of the speaker at the time that they are speaking.

At the moment I have everything working; however, I know I probably did it the most inefficient way possible. I hard coded 48 if statements for every top and bottom of the hour...yeah I know. Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
setInterval(getSchedule, 1000);

function getSchedule(){
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()
var curMin = today.getMinutes()

if (curHr == 1 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "John";
} else if (curHr == 1 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "George";
} else if (curHr == 2 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jerry";
} else if (curHr == 2 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bailey";
} else if (curHr == 3 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Albert";
} else if (curHr == 3 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Smith";
} else if (curHr == 4 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ralph";
} else if (curHr == 4 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Matt";
} else if (curHr == 5 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Carl";
} else if (curHr == 5 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bob";
} else if (curHr == 6 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jared";
} else if (curHr == 6 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ben";
} else if (curHr == 7 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Alberto";
} else if (curHr == 7 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Lopez";
} else if (curHr == 8 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Anguelo";
} else if (curHr == 8 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Tony";
} else if (curHr == 9 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Pam";
} else if (curHr == 9 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "John";
} else if (curHr == 10 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Mark";
} else if (curHr == 10 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Luke";
} else if (curHr == 11 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paul";
} else if (curHr == 11 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Geoff";
} else if (curHr == 12 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gavin";
} else if (curHr == 12 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Peter";
} else if (curHr == 13 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Thomas";
} else if (curHr == 13 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Suarez";
} else if (curHr == 14 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Diane";
} else if (curHr == 14 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Al";
} else if (curHr == 15 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Zak";
} else if (curHr == 15 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Shane";
} else if (curHr == 16 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jack";
} else if (curHr == 16 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jill";
} else if (curHr == 17 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jeff";
} else if (curHr == 17 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Scott";
} else if (curHr == 18 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ramsey";
} else if (curHr == 18 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paul";
} else if (curHr == 19 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bob";
} else if (curHr == 19 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jack";
} else if (curHr == 20 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Matt";
} else if (curHr == 20 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Nate";
} else if (curHr == 21 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Sam";
} else if (curHr == 21 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Jenny";
} else if (curHr == 22 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Michelle";
} else if (curHr == 22 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "George";
} else if (curHr == 23 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bill";
} else if (curHr == 23 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bob";
} else if (curHr == 24 && curMin < 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bill";
} else if (curHr == 24 && curMin >= 30) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bob";
} 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I would like to know if there is a way to simplify my code. I was thinking about using an array that has all the names of the speakers; however, how would I iterate through it at the exact times.

Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is crazy over complicated lol.

Comment: @S.Walker How is that helpful? The question says they know it's probably not a good way to do it.

Comment: You should research [working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). Create a schedule object with properties whose names correspond to specific time values, and whose properties are objects representing the time slot (these objects can contain relevant information that you want to display such as title, description, speaker, etc.). These objects can be serialized or deserialized to / from JSON for ease of maintenance in the future.

Comment: Review of functional code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Such questions belong on [codereview.se]. However, be sure to read their [on-topic page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting your question there to be sure it's on-topic in it's current state.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all those if statements with:

```
  var demoHTML = curHr + (curMin < 30 ? ":00" : ":30");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = demoHTML
```

So that the whole function becomes:

```
 function getSchedule(){
      var today = new Date()
      var curHr = today.getHours()
      var curMin = today.getMinutes()
      var demoHTML = curHr + (curMin < 30 ? ":00" : ":30");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = demoHTML
}
```

Comment: While this is _a_ literal answer to the question, this is very far from what the OP actually needs (which is a better understanding of objects and functional programming).

Comment: Yeah I updated the post to be more specific. I want to display the name of the speaker at the allotted time when they are speaking. Displaying the time was just to show it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not really get what you want to do!

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test Java Script</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
setInterval(getSchedule, 1000);

var speakers = { "10:00": "kenvin", "10:30": "faker" };

function getSchedule(){
var today = new Date()
var curHr = today.getHours()
var curMin = today.getMinutes()

console.log([curHr, (curMin >= 30) ? "30" : "00"].join(":"));
var key = [curHr, (curMin >= 30) ? "30" : "00"].join(":");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key + " - " + speakers[key];
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to display the speakers name at the time that they are speaking.

Answer (score 0):

A single IF statement would suffice...

```
if (curMin < 30) { demo.innerHTML = curHr+':00';} else { demo.innerHTML = curHr+':30';}
```